# Xcode Code Sign Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

this is problem that has been going on for months and I can't seem to figure it out. I used to be able to test apps on my iPhone, however I restored my computer. After the restore I once again downloaded all the certificates and created the new app id's and provisioning profiles. Everything is set up correctly but I keep getting this error:

Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.redinnovatipntech.MyAppName' could not be found

I've searched everywhere for the answer to no avail... hopefully one of you can help, i'm getting close to release and I need to begin real world testing. Thank you!

Comment: Check your  application's Identifier 'com.redinnovatipntech.MyAppName' is same as Bundle identifier. Is it same?

Comment: have you installed provisioning profile?

Comment: Try to remove in "Window" tab => Organizer, the provisioning that are in your device. Then re-add them.
Also make sure that your "Bundle identifier" is matching with selected provisioning in Build Settings.

Comment: are you getting solution.

Comment: I will try removing and adding the provisioning profile once again. Yes the Bundle identifier does match.

Comment: Thank you Khawar, you got everything sorted out. If you can post an answer instead of the comment soon i'll give you the points. What had happened was I had the provisioning profile installed on my phone, but it wasn't in the "Library" provisioning profile section. This caused the problem. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First You need to set that provisioning profile name to bundle identifier.

**com.redinnovatipntech.MyAppName** your bundle identifier name is same as your provisioning profile name.and you must select the code signing identity from build setting if your certificate is created then appears here you must select that.

you must try this this will really help you.

Comment: I will try this again as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your bundle Identifier is same as  application's Identifier 'com.redinnovatipntech.MyAppName**

[image]

Comment: What if the default bundle identifier Xcode provides has the reverse domain "com.redinnovationtech" correct but the app name portion is greyed out and un-editable? Could that be the problem even though they match, the bundle identifier I created in the provisioning portal?